# How to add both Sign In and Sign Up in one Screen in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: SignIn & SignUp screen]

I am trying to build the same screen as shown in the image but couldn't get the best result. I have tried using Tabs; is there any other component that I can use to build the same screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to not use an external component for this case, because it's a simple switch tab that you can code yourself without importing external libraries, plus you will control more efficiently the behavior of what you want to do in your screen

A solution could be something like this, I used a simple state to hide/appear each login/signup block  ([snack link](https://snack.expo.io/m7bC4GPRo) ):

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showLogin: true,
    };
  }

  _handlePress = () => {
    this.setState({ showLogin: !this.state.showLogin });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress} 
          style={{ margin: 24, color: this.state.showLogin ? "grey" : "black" }}>
            {"Login"}
      </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress} 
          style={{ margin: 24, color: this.state.showLogin ? "black" : "grey" }}>
            {"Signup"}
      </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {
          this.state.showLogin ?
            // content of login
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                {"input login 0"}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                {"input login 1"}
              </Text>
            </View>
            :

            // content of signup
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                {"input signup 2"}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
                {"input signup 3"}
              </Text>
            </View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 24,
  },
  container2: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    marginTop: 0,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```